# Sending time in influxdb with python

Tags: python, database, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am sending data in influx through python. Everything works fine but the time column. I am sending different time values each time.

Suppose if I want to send now-15m time into influx, then I am using the below code to do that:-

```
time = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

json_stats = [{"measurement": "test", "tags": {"domain": domain}, "fields": {"tot_record": tot_record,
                                                                                    "time":time
                                                                                            }}]
```

Before sending it into influx i am using print to confirm the timestamp and it prints the expected value but it is getting overwritten with the current time.

Influx is replacing the time column with its own time which is the time on which the values are being stored.

Why influx is replacing my time values with the current timestamp and how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by passing time outside of the field column :-

```
time = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

json_stats = [{"measurement": "test", "tags": {"domain": domain},"time":time, "fields": {"tot_record": tot_record,
```